# How to replace the selected box value while storing on array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Folks Hope, you have a nice day I need some help regarding this I have four dropdowns select
box something like this

box 1

```html
 <h1> Box 1</h1>
 <select id="RVP" name="RVP" class="susel" style="max-width:90%;">
                                            <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option><option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option><option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option><option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option><option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option><option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option><option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option><option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>    </select>
                       <h1> Box 2</h1>
 <select id="LVP" name="LVP" class="susel" style="max-width:90%;">
                                            <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option><option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option><option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option><option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option><option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option><option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option><option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option><option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>    </select>
                       <h1> Box 3</h1>
 <select id="LHP" name="LHP" class="susel" style="max-width:90%;">
                                            <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option><option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option><option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option><option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option><option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option><option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option><option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option><option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>    </select>
                       <h1> Box 4</h1>
 <select id="RHP" name="RHP" class="susel" style="max-width:90%;">
                                            <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option><option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option><option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option><option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option><option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option><option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option><option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option><option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>    </select>
```

so what I trying to do is pick four values from the dropdowns above and find the max value from it
I kind of achieve that goal but I have a problem so here is my js that help me to achieve that

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
rvp=$('#RVP');
lvp=$('#LVP');
rhp=$('#RHP');
lhp=$('#LHP');

var selectors=Array(rvp,lvp,rhp,lhp);
var values=Array();
selectors.forEach(function(el){
    $(el).on('click',function(e){
      selvalue= el.find(":selected").val()
       if(selvalue!='none'){
           console.log(el);
        values.push(selvalue);
       console.log(values);
      var maxnum= Math.max.apply(null,values);
      console.log(maxnum);};})
```

so let's pick 1.00 from box1, 2.00 from box 2, 3.00 from box 3 and 4.00 from box 4 and store them in an array called values and find the max value and I get 4 that's great but when I change the box 4 value to 3.50 I want to replace the 4 with 3.5 in that value array something like if I change the
box4 dropdown value in front-end  it should change the value in the array also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your solution a bit:

Gave a class to all the selectors, and hooked on those. Take a look

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  const selectorFields = $('.value-selector')

  /* Returns the highest selected value */
  function calculateMax() {
    const selectorValues = selectorFields.map(s => parseFloat($(selectorFields[s]).find(":selected").val()));
    console.log(Math.max(...selectorValues))
  }
  
  /* Calc max initially */
  calculateMax()
  
  /* Calc max on every change */
  selectorFields.on('change', function() {
    calculateMax();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Box 1</h1>
<select id="RVP" name="RVP" class="susel value-selector" style="max-width:90%;">
  <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option>
  <option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option>
  <option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option>
  <option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option>
  <option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option>
  <option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option>
  <option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option>
  <option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>
</select>
<h1> Box 2</h1>
<select id="LVP" name="LVP" class="susel value-selector" style="max-width:90%;">
  <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option>
  <option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option>
  <option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option>
  <option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option>
  <option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option>
  <option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option>
  <option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option>
  <option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>
</select>
<h1> Box 3</h1>
<select id="LHP" name="LHP" class="susel value-selector" style="max-width:90%;">
  <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option>
  <option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option>
  <option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option>
  <option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option>
  <option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option>
  <option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option>
  <option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option>
  <option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>
</select>
<h1> Box 4</h1>
<select id="RHP" name="RHP" class="susel value-selector" style="max-width:90%;">
  <option value="0.50">Up 0.50</option>
  <option value="1.00">Up 1.00</option>
  <option value="1.50">Up 1.50</option>
  <option value="2.00">Up 2.00</option>
  <option value="2.50">Up 2.50</option>
  <option value="3.00">Up 3.00</option>
  <option value="3.50">Up 3.50</option>
  <option value="4.00">Up 4.00</option>
</select>
```